# PhpStorm Git Password Authentication failed

Tags: git, authorization, phpstorm

I have a confusing problem with my PhpStorm 2017.2.1.
I can't clone Repos from my intern Git-Server:

```
Clone failed
Authentication failed for 'https://git......'
```

But if I clone from my terminal it is working.

I tried to reinstall PhpStorm without import settings etc. but the problem is still active.

OS: Win7
Git: 2.11.0
PhpStorm: 2017.2.1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a solution. I reinstall Git with "Git Credential Manager for Windows" and set the storage with following command:

`git config --global credential.helper wincred`

The solution I found here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5343146/7387397

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1**
File -> Invalidate Caches/ Restart -> Invalidate and Restart

**Solution 2**

1. Go to file
2. Setting
3. Appearance and Behavior
4. System Setting
5. under password select the "DO not save , forget passwords after restart" option
   and restart the PHPStorm and get update